# function call for dynamically added form elements

Tags: jquery

i have a form with an input field and I'm adding another input field with a button. I have a function call on a 'keyup' event for every input field, but this function call is only working for the first input field, the dynamically added input fields are not triggering the function. How can I get it to work with all input fields?

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emjay__/RdsFa/) to see my example.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div id="serials">
        <div id="serial_0">
            Serial 0: <input type="text" name="serial_0" id="serial_0" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="addSerial">add another field</button>
</form>
```

Here is my JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[id^=serial]').on("keyup", validateSerial);

    $("#addSerial").click(function () {
        $("#serials").append('' +
            '<div id="serial_' + $("#serials > div").size() + '">' +
                'Serial '+ $("#serials > div").size() +': <input type="text"' + 
                'name="serial_' + $("#serials > div").size() + '"' +
                'id="serial_' + $("#serials > div").size() + '"' +
            '</div>' +
        '');
    });

});

function validateSerial(){

    var inputFieldNumber = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+$/);
    alert(inputFieldNumber);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use event delegation model here

```
$("#serials").on("keyup", 'input[id^=serial]', validateSerial);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working. :) Could you please explain what's the difference between your function call and my function call?

Comment: @emjay when you use `$('input[id^=serial]')` to register the event handlers then it will register the handlers to only those elements which exists in the dom when the code was executed

Comment: I think you mean 'delegation' not 'propagation' even a delegated event use propagation

Comment: @emjay when you use the above model, then  the event handler is added to `$("#serials")`, but since the js event model propagates events to parent elements any keyup in the child elements will get propagated to this element and then jQuery performs a test to see whether the target meets the selector passed in the second parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[id^=serial]').on("keyup", validateSerial);

    $("#addSerial").click(function () {
        $("#serials").append('' +
            '<div id="serial_' + $("#serials > div").size() + '">' +
                'Serial '+ $("#serials > div").size() +': <input type="text"' + 
                'name="serial_' + $("#serials > div").size() + '"' +
                'id="serial_' + $("#serials > div").size() + '"' +
            '</div>' +
        '');
        $('input[id^=serial]').on("keyup", validateSerial);
    });

});

function validateSerial(){

    var inputFieldNumber = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+$/);
    alert(inputFieldNumber);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RdsFa/1/

```
$(document).on("keyup",'input[id^=serial]', validateSerial);
```